# Removing full site from Google Index

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

My URL is: http://LawMirror.com - (Online Legal Resources)

I want to remove the contents from Google Index. Google Index include my websites huge number of Pages indexed in Google Index about 5,000,000 Pages earlier but now left pages are 3,025,000.
My URL is: http://LawMirror.com - (Online Legal Resources)

I want to remove the contents from Google Index. Google Index include my websites huge number of Pages indexed in Google Index about 5,000,000 Pages earlier but now left pages are 3,025,000.

I have made the following things but the removal of pages are very slow pace.

Robots.txt

User-agent: * Disallow: /

.htaccess

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Googlebot/2.1.*$
rewriterule .* - [G]
```

The is the content returned to Googlebot when it try's to crawl the content

HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
Date: Sat, 05 Jan 2013 12:39:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.3.19
Content-Length: 661
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

I had also used the html meta tag noindex, no follow but no effect as:

I had also submitted for website removal but the speed of removing of contents is very slow. In last 35 days the only few are pages are removed. My website is also removed from Google Search Index but Google Webmasters - Health -> Index status still showing 3,025,000 page and If I re-submit the site they will show already indexed pages. How can I increase the speed to remove pages.

The is the content returned to Googlebot when it try's to crawl the content

```
HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
Date: Sat, 05 Jan 2013 12:39:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.3.19
Content-Length: 661
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I had also used the html meta tag noindex, no follow but no effect as:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

I had also submitted for website removal but the speed of removing of contents is very slow. In last 35 days the only few are pages are removed. My website is also removed from Google Search Index but Google Webmasters - Health -> Index status still showing 3,025,000 page and If I re-submit the site they will show already indexed pages. How can I increase the speed to remove pages.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to return a 410 each time a page is requested. It will accelerate deindexing. Make sure no page is blocked in your `robots.txt`.

Comment: By using Disallow: /, you did not let bots access the pages, and they did not see the 410. This is why your pages were slowly deindexed. It would have been much faster otherwise. Kindly read my answer, I said no pages should be blocked in your robots.txt.